# filters.assign doesn't work

Tags: python, las, pdal

I want to make all the Z values of the input .LAS file equal to 0. Here is my pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
        in,
        {
            "type": "filters.assign",
            "value":
                [
                    "Z=Z*0"
                ]
        },
        out,
    ]
```

However, the output file contains exactly the same height as in the input. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug. Here's another way to set Z values to 0.

```
    {
      "type": "filters.assign",
      "value": "Z = 0"
    }
```